# Be sure to install time zone support - https://github.com/ankane/groupdate#for-mysql in RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to send the placement papers but when i start the time and submit the button it gives me an error

> Be sure to install time zone support - https://github.com/ankane/groupdate#for-mysql

What should i do to solve this problem?

**view**

```
 <%= pie_chart @score[0]%> 
 <%= line_chart Result.group(:name,:percentage).count %> 
 <%= column_chart Result.group(:name,:percentage).count%>
 <%= bar_chart Result.group(:name).group(:percentage).count %>
 <%= line_chart Result.group_by_hour(:created_at).count %>
 <%= line_chart [
{name: "Cantidad de voluntarios en estado activo", data: {Time.new => 20} },
{name: "Study", data: {Time.new => 30} },
{name: "Conversation", data: {Time.new => 50} } ],
{library: {hAxis: {title: "Tiempo", format: 'MMM y'}, vAxis: {title: "Valores"}}} %>
```

**controller**

```
  def save_test
    @test = params[:question]
    @placement_exam = PlacementExam.find(params[:placement_exam_id])
    @student = Student.find(params[:student_id])
    @score = PlacementExam.calculateres(@test, @placement_exam.id, @student)
  end
```

Comment: Did you tried installing time zone support as per the link https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/time-zone-support.html

Comment: @AnkitG Yes i tried but couldn't find any proper solution..Can you please help me...

Answer (score 3):

I know this is late but the following worked for me:-

```
mysql_tzinfo_to_sql /usr/share/zoneinfo | mysql -u root -p mysql
```

Enter your password and ignore any errors.

**Restart the mysql server**

Comment: Interesting... is the msyql server restart necessary? For me, it wasn't. But what was your outcome?